# join between two table in spring and hibernate Mysql

Tags: spring, hibernate, join

Table 1 name is users field name is userid ,roleid and username
Table 2 name is roles field name is roleid and rolename

I want to create relation between these two table.

I have follows more than 10 example. but i have not got any result.

Please help me and create the code according to me

Thanks

Comment: There are various online tutorials you can follow. http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-with-annotation
http://coderevisited.com/beginning-jpa-2-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a relation between two entities/tables, you need to determine the type of relation you want to represent, whether that is a *one-to-one*, *one-to-many*, *many-to-one*, or *many-to-many*.

For your use case between a `User` and `Role`, this is typically a *many-to-many* because a User is associated to many roles and a role may be associated to many differing users.

User.java:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  /* other things */
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "user_roles")
  private List<Role> roles;
}
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
public class Role {
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
  private List<User> users;
}
```

In this particular example, the relationship is owned by the `User` beacuse typically you would have roles created separately and then you associate a user to a set of roles.